# Iterate through sql result in shell script

Tags: sql, bash, shell

I am using the below code

```
tablelist=`SELECT tablename from List`
echo "table list is $tablelist"
```

Result is displayed as

```
table list is Table1
Table2
Table3
Table4
```

I want to iterate through the result. Please suggest how I can achieve this. If I loop through the current tablelist, it prints the whole list in inside loop.

Comment: See: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution

Comment: I tried to correct your English, but I do not understand what you mean with the last sentence: "If I loop through the current tablelist, it prints the whole list in inside loop."

Comment: Which code did you use to iterate through the result?

Comment: I wanted to iterate through the result of sql which was $tablelist. I found solution.
echo "${tablelist}" |while read line 
By using this i was able to retrieve each tablename

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**${tablelist}**" is not a one-line result.  It is multiple lines, one entry per line.  So ... it is best not to treat it as a simple string.  You should treat it as a file.

```
#!/bin/bash

#tablelist=`SELECT tablename from List`

cat >tables.list <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
Table1
Table2
Table3
Table4
EnDoFiNpUt

i=1

#echo "${tablelist}" |
cat tables.list |
while read table
do
        echo -e "\t [${i}] TABLE: '${table}' ..."
        echo -e "\t\t ... replace this line by some action using '${table}' ...\n"
        i=$((i+=1))
done
```

The output of that looks like this:

[1] TABLE: 'Table1' ...
... replace this line by some action using 'Table1' ...

[2] TABLE: 'Table2' ...
... replace this line by some action using 'Table2' ...

[3] TABLE: 'Table3' ...
... replace this line by some action using 'Table3' ...

[4] TABLE: 'Table4' ...
... replace this line by some action using 'Table4' ...